# Atom IDE : Vertical code folding lines to improve code readability

Tags: atom-editor, code-readability, code-folding

I have searched on this for quite some time and am unable to find an answer after which I've turned to you folks.  I am working with the Atom IDE and my query is very simple - I would like to have to vertical faint lines which run from beginning of a code block to its end which improves code readability.  I've made several searches on google for an answer to this but am unable to get a solution.

I don't want to fold the code.  I just want those awesome lines.

**What it is:**

[image]

**What I would like:**

[image: http://in.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2015b/matlab/matlab_prog/code_folding_pointer.png]

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to settings and check "show indent guide".

You may also try to install package "indent-guide-improved".